# How can I apply condition to Insert data in Oracle Forms 6i

Tags: oracle, oracleforms

I have table `DOC_CUST_PRODUCT (DOC_CODE, CUST_CODE, P_CODE)`

I want to restrict insertion and show message when `DOC_CODE` has more than 5   different `CUST_CODE`

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT CUST_CODE) 
INTO Y 
FROM BP_DOC_CUST_PRODUCT 
WHERE DOC_CODE = :DOC_CODE; 

IF NVL(Y,0) > 4 THEN 
   MESSAGE('Sorry, Can Not Entry More Than 5 Chemist...'); 
   MESSAGE('Sorry, Can Not Entry More Than 5 Chemist...');
```

but it doesn't work.

Comment: Start by fixing your keyboard. Its shift key seems to be blocked.

Comment: Writing all uppercase is considered SHOUTING and rude. But more importantly your question lacks a lot of information. Please read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT CUST_CODE) INTO Y FROM BP_DOC_CUST_PRODUCT WHERE DOC_CODE=:DOC_CODE; 
 IF NVL(Y,0)>4  THEN
  MESSAGE('Sorry, Can Not Entry More Than 5 Chemist...');
  MESSAGE('Sorry, Can Not Entry More Than 5 Chemist...');

Comment: bt it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Where did you put that code? Should be `WHEN-VALIDATE-ITEM` trigger on `DOC_CODE` item.

If there are two (or more) items named `DOC_CODE`, Forms doesn't know which one you're referencing - I suggest you to always specify block name with the item name.

Code you posted isn't complete - variable declaration is missing, `IF` doesn't have an `END IF`. I don't know whether you really didn't do that, or you just didn't post everything you wrote (by the way, how are we supposed to know that?).

`COUNT` function can't return `NULL` as a result, so applying `NVL` to the variable `Y` is superfluous.

The following code *should* be OK (if you fix what's missing - a block name).

```
-- WHEN-VALIDATE-ITEM trigger on :BLOCK_NAME.DOC_CODE item

declare
  l_count number;
begin
  select count(distinct b.cust_code)
    into l_count
    from bp_doc_cust_product b
    where b.doc_code = :block_name.doc_code;

  if l_count = 5 then
     message('Sorry, ...');
     message('Sorry, ...');
  end if;
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve this by adding a post-query trigger to your block. If the count returns more than 5 elements, just change the ENABLE property of your item to disable it otherwise enable it.

To display your message before inserting a new record, you can also use an 'pre-insert' trigger on your block and check the result of the count, then display your message :

```
IF EL_COUNT > 5 THEN
 Message('Sorry, Can Not Entry More Than 5 Chemist...');
 RAISE Form_trigger_Failure;
END IF;
```